# how to find the lowest of the 10 *number of answers same* and overwrite a higher *number of answers same* and modify the *person ID* key with it

Tags: php, arrays

I'm writing a script in PHP that compares people together based on the number of same answers in a survey.  I use an array like this:

[*person ID*]=>*number of answers same*

to  store the 10 people closest to the one I am comparing with.

I need to figure out how to find the lowest of the 10 *number of answers same* and overwrite a higher *number of answers same* and modify the *person ID* key with it.

Comment: Can you rephrase "the lowest of the 10 number of answers same and overwrite a higher number of answers same and modify the person ID key with it."? I can't understand what you are asking. You should have already noticed: English is not my idiom of choice.

Comment: Hmm.
I need to keep an array full of the 10 highest matches. 

This problem was solved according to Tim's reccomendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it just be easier to keep your array sorted by number of same answers? Maybe even just add the new person, resort the array and remove the first/last..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could solve this in SQL very easily, but will require a great deal of work to do in PHP.

Comment: Is this a solution or a critque?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the entries according to the delta to `person.number_of_answers`. Eg.:

```
function cmp_by_delta($a, $b) {
  if ($a->delta == $b->delta) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a->delta < $b->delta) ? -1 : 1;
}
// calculate delta for each entry
foreach ($entries as $person) {
  $person->delta = abs($target_person->number_of_answers - $person->number_of_answers);
}
// sort entries by delta
usort($entries, 'cmp_by_delta');
// take 10 first matches from sorted array
$10_best_matches = array_slice($entries, 0, 10);
```

Of course, this can be done much prettier and much more efficiently in a database:

```
select * from people
order by abs(number_of_answers - :target_number_of_answers)
limit 10;
```

Comment: Did this ever work?  https://3v4l.org/M5FI4  Can we close and purge this page now?